# issue : " List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic> " in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am Practicing to building an app, in which I need to read data from API. I am trying to parse data through JSON

here is link of the api : https://fakestoreapi.com/products

Here is the model class :

```
class ProductModel {
  int id = 0;
  String title = "";
  double price = 0;
  String description = "";
  String category = "";
  String image = "";
  List<Rating> rating = [];

  ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    price = json['price'];
    description = json['description'];
    category = json['category'];
    image = json['image'];

    rating = List.from(json['rating']).map((e) => Rating.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['image'] = this.image;

    data['rateing'] = rating.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    return data;
  }
}

class Rating {
  double rate = 0;
  int count = 0;

  Rating.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    rate = json['rate'];
    count = json['count'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['rate'] = this.rate;
    data['count'] = this.count;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here is the api call function :

```
Future getAllProduct() async {
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.get(_baseUrl);
      if (response.statusCode == 200 && response.data !== null) {
   
        print(response.data);
        return ProductModel.fromJson(response.data);
      } // error response must be used in the production
      else {
        return response.statusCode.toString();
      }
    } on DioError catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print("Exception occured: $error StackTrace: $stacktrace");
    }
  }
```

The error I am currently facing is :
`List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>`

Answer (score 1):

because `response.data` is list of `ProductModel`

try this:

```
Future<List<ProductModel>> getAllProduct() async {
    List<ProductModel> _list = [];
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.get(_baseUrl);
      if (response.statusCode == 200 && response.data !== null) {
        response.data.forEach((e){
          _list.add(ProductModel.fromJson(e));
        });
      } // error response must be used in the production
      else {
        return [];
      }
    } on DioError catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print("Exception occured: $error StackTrace: $stacktrace");
    }
    return _list;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When the response is successful, you can return it as follows:

```
return (response.data as List).map((e) => ProductModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the model as per map, List and null check. This will work. It is mostly because we are assigning the model wrongly. We have to tell the dart correctly which datatypes it is.

[image: Code snippet]

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your answer so that it can be read on all devices, edited, copied as text, and found through search. As it stands now, your image makes it hard to view and use your answer. See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.  If you are still getting an error, please ping me by saying `@StephenOstermiller` in a comment and I will try to help you.